# Approximation of bounded simply connected domains on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

This seems to be a true statement, but I am not sure if I can write down a valid proof:

> Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded simply connected open set (with no regularity assumptions on $\partial \Omega$). Then for all $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a compact $K_\epsilon \subseteq_c \Omega$ with $\partial K_\epsilon$ being $C^1$, such that $d(x,\partial \Omega) < \epsilon$ for all $x \in \partial K_\epsilon$.

My first thought was to use smooth approximation of continuous functions, provided by tubular neighborhood theorem. But since there is no regularity assumptions on $\partial \Omega$, it may not even be a Jordan curve, so I would not be able to (even locally) consider $\partial \Omega$ as the graph of a continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

As specified, the task is unexpectedly easy:
Pick $a\in\partial \Omega$. By definition of boundary, the $\epsilon$-ball around $a$, $B_\epsilon(a)$, intersects $\Omega$. Pick $b\in\Omega\cap B_\epsilon(a)$. Then $B_r(b)\subseteq_c \Omega$ provided $r$ is small enough, say $r<r_0$. Now let $$K_\epsilon = B_{\min\{r_0,\epsilon-d(a,b)\}/2}(b)$$
Its boundary is a circle and each of its  points is less than $\epsilon$  away from $a\in\partial\Omega$.

Comment: Aha I see what you did! And of course this was not my intention. But I think I can use compactness of $\partial K_\epsilon$, and find a smooth curve that embeds in a finite $\epsilon$-ball cover of the boundary. Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: @P.Factor My guess to what you actually wanted was that $K\subset\Omega$ is also simply connected, has a smooth boundary and the Hausdorff distance between $\partial K$ and $\partial \Omega$ is $<\epsilon$

Comment: That was my intention, but I don't think this is possible any more...